# Custom Rails route test fails despite the route loading OK in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, routes

I am getting an error testing a controller route despite being able to successfully load it via the browser. Rails4 + rspec.

Any ideas?

```
#controller spec 
describe PublicSitesController do

  describe "GET index" do
    it "returns success" do
      get :index                        #line 7 in the spec file
      response.status.should == 200
    end
  end

end


#routes
get ":site_name/:page_name", to: "public_sites#show"
get ":site_name", to: 'public_sites#index'
get "/", to: 'public_sites#root'


#controller
class PublicSitesController < ApplicationController

  def root
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

end

#the error:
Failures:

1) PublicSitesController GET index returns success
   Failure/Error: get :index
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
     No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"public_sites"}
   # ./spec/controllers/public_sites_controller_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here are the relevant routes via rake routes:

```
      GET    /:site_name/:page_name(.:format)                  public_sites#show
      POST   /:site_name/:page_name(.:format)                  public_sites#receive_form
      GET    /:site_name(.:format)                             public_sites#index
      GET    /                                                 public_sites#root
```

Comment: copy the output of "rake routes"

Comment: added the rake routes output as requested

Comment: maybe try `get '/public_sites/index'` to see if the :site_name symbol in the routes can be "resolved" to its value in the test scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some parameter on the request, the router doesn't know what to do with ":site_name", try something like:

```
get :index, site_name: 'something'
```

edit:

when you call get/post/etc inside a test you call the action name with that method, not the url, that way the controller test is independant of the url that make that action work (you can change the url and the controller will still work)

your route tells rails that it need some parameter named "site_name" so you need to tell rails what's inside "site_name" with a parameter for the action

if you want you can have routing tests, there you can test that some url goes to some controller's action with some value on some parameter https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/routing-specs

when you open the site on a browser you are not calling the action, you are actually running your whole application, then the routing system calls the controller's action

edit 2:
if you want to test the show action you should call it with

```
get :show, site_name: 'some_site', page_name: 'some_page'
```

Comment: Thank you, this made the test pass. However, `get '/the-site-name'` results in `No route matches {:controller=>"public_sites", :action=>"/the-site-name/the-page-name"}` ... while a browser test shows the correct view. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Thank you. I have passing routing tests `{ :get => "/the-site-name/the-page-name"}.should route_to("public_sites#show", site_name: "the-site-name", page_name: "the-page-name")` and this is partially why the situation was so confusing.